# juju illegal base64 data at input byte 9

Tags: juju

After bootstrap a environment via manual provisioning, juju give me the following output for `juju status`:

```
ERROR Unable to connect to environment "manual". 
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
illegal base64 data at input byte 9
```

And doing bootstrap again shows me:

```
WARNING ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/ayrton/.juju/environments/manual.jenv"
ERROR illegal base64 data at input byte 9
```

The first bootstrap shows me no error, but the status crash as above and the second one output is just the base64 error.

My juju version is 1.19.4-trusty-amd64, running in trusty 64.

The bootstrap environment is a VPS with 1GB of memory, 20GB of hd and precise 64bits.

Please, let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: If your environments.yaml doesn't contain any sensitive information, can you pastebin it? Also, have you tried Juju 1.20(.1)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by doing a `sudo apt-get install dbus` under my bootstrap environment.